# Get position of CCSprite

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cgpoint, ccnode

Im a bit confused. I am trying to move one CCSprite onto the position of another CCSprite. I figured it would be simple, but the CCSprite isn't positioning correctly. I have 2 CCSprites:

```
//Get Position of EMPTY SPRITE
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite*)[self getChildByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", kEMPTY] recursively:NO];

 //GET DRAGGED SQUARE
 CCSprite *spriteMove = (CCSprite*)[self getChildByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", DragStartSquare] recursively:NO];
```

I am then trying to get the position of the EMPTY SPRITE (Its not actually empty) by doing

```
CGPoint worldCoord = [sprite convertToWorldSpace: sprite.position];
```

I am then animating it with:

```
id action1 = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration position:worldCoord];
```

This sends the sprite off the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert back into the target sprite's node space:

```
CGPoint targetNodeCoord = [spriteMove convertToNodeSpace: [sprite convertToWorldSpace: sprite.position]];
CCAction *action1 = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration position:targetNodeCoord];
```

Comment: Thanks. Its closer but still positions it wrong. It goes above.

Comment: Are the two sprites the same size? Do they have the same anchor point? Also, just noticed the sprites are both children of the same parent node, so I think you can skip all the coordinate transformations entirely.